# How do I retrieve the referrer page url once a custom error page is returned

Tags: asp.net

I'd like to capture the http referrer url following the rendering of a custom error page.

I have this set in my web.config

```
<customErrors mode="On">
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="/StaticError.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

In the OnLoad(EventArgs e) event -- I'm trying to do this, but it appears to be too late.

```
this.txtReferrer.Text = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
```

Is it possible to capture the referrer url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your custom error page (/StaticError.aspx), Request.UrlReferrer will be the page that referred/posted to the page that is erroring.  If your first request to the website is the erroring page, it will be blank, as there is no referrer.

If you are looking for the page that actually errored, it will be posted to the query string when directed to your custom error page.

VB.NET

```
this.txtReferrer.Text = Request.QueryString("aspxerrorpath")
```

C#

```
this.txtReferrer.Text = Request.QueryString["aspxerrorpath"];
```